# Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.data.map is not a function, Map error to render Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I don't know what is happening with the component im trying to map an array of objects from mongo here but it is no showing nothing to printInventory, but if i call to *this.props.inventory* and it takes all the data! What is happening?

```
 printInventory = () => {
    this.props.inventory.map((inventory) => {
        return (
            <CardInventario
                cardTitle={inventory.name}
                quantity={inventory.quantity}
                description={inventory.price}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

in these function.

Next I going to show the actions and the reducers:

inventoryReducer:

```
import {TAKE_INVENTORY} from '../../types/inventoryTypes';

const INITIAL_STATE ={
    inventory: []
}

function invetoryReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE,action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case TAKE_INVENTORY:
            return {...state, inventory: action.payload}
            break;
        default:
            return state;
            break;
    }
}

export default invetoryReducer;
```

and here is the inventoryActions:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { TAKE_INVENTORY } from '../../types/inventoryTypes'

export const takeInventory = () => async (dispatch) =>{
    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3001/inventory')
        dispatch({
            type: TAKE_INVENTORY,
            payload: res.data
        })
    
}
```

And the full component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import axios from 'axios'
/* Components and Styles */
import CardInventario from '../components/CardInventario'
import '../assets/styles/container/Stock.scss'
/* Redux */
import * as inventoryActions from '../actions/inventoryActions'

class Stock extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.takeInventory();
    }

    printInventory = () => {
        this.props.inventory.map((inventory) => {
            return (
                <CardInventario
                    cardTitle={inventory.name}
                    quantity={inventory.quantity}
                    description={inventory.price}
                />
            )
        })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.inventory)
        return (
            <>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="additem">
                        <Link to="/additem" className="additem__link">
                            <p className="link-add">
                                Añadir Item a Stock
                            </p>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="stock" key="stock">
                        {this.printInventory()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (reducers) => {
    return reducers.inventoryReducer;
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, inventoryActions)(Stock);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please use the correct mapping.
inventoryReducer is not the one you're looking to map.
inventory inside that object is the one you want.

```
const mapStateToProps = (reducers) => {
    return reducers.inventoryReducer.inventory;
}
```

Also if you get data in this.props.inventory, it should be related to duplicated keys
Please try the following

```
printInventory = () => {
    this.props.inventory.map((inventory, index) => {
        return (
            <CardInventario
                key={index}
                cardTitle={inventory.name}
                quantity={inventory.quantity}
                description={inventory.price}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

If you don't have id, it is possible to use index instead (not recommended though)

```
printInventory = () => {
    this.props.inventory.map((inventory) => {
        return (
            <CardInventario
                key={inventory.id}
                cardTitle={inventory.name}
                quantity={inventory.quantity}
                description={inventory.price}
            />
        )
    })
}
```

Comment: Error? What error do you see?
You mean it's still empty?
If you meant empty then I doubt the rendering part of CardInventario itself

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: _this.props.inventory.map is not a function
    at Stock.printInventory (Stock.jsx:19)
    at Stock.render (Stock.jsx:43)

Comment: he above error occurred in the <Stock> component:
    in Stock (created by ConnectFunction)
    in ConnectFunction (created by Context.Consumer)

Comment: Well I updated the answer. It looks like your mapping function was in correct.
Reducer there is an object not the array.
So inventory inside it should be the one you wanted to populate

Comment: Yes im looking to that but in the payload im passing an object, and these object have an data, these data was an array of objects

Comment: Please show me the output of this.props.inventory you see here
And have you tried my solution above? I updated the answer

Comment: {data: Array(15), message: "products listed"}
data: Array(15)
0: {_id: "5f4145cd79fb8e590426f479", name: "Peras", price: 22, quantity: 12345, products: null}
1: {_id: "5f41d3afdae77551e806ccf5", name: " rico", price: 2, quantity: 20}
2: {_id: "5f41d50f09a6f74ca0bd219d", data: null}
3: {_id: "5f41d5b14b3c75521411d702", products: null}
4: {_id: "5f41d6ae002bb146207c75fa", products: null}
5: {_id: "5f41d6c6d588451d44298b9c", data: null}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221068/discussion-between-softdev-and-felipe-olaya-ospina).